# How to solve flutter build apk error "Could not dispatch a message to the daemon"

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle

I was run `flutter build apk` command then I am facing this exception below:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Could not dispatch a message to the daemon.



The message received from the daemon indicates that the daemon has disappeared.

Build request sent: Build{id=68f521a5-3aa3-4a37-be49-737d539a0090, currentDir=C:\Users\Lenovo\AndroidStudioProjects\subidha-pharmacy\android}

Attempting to read last messages from the daemon log...

Daemon pid: 10516

  log file: C:\Users\Lenovo\.gradle\daemon\5.1.1\daemon-10516.out.log

----- Last  20 lines from daemon log file - daemon-10516.out.log -----

14:41:46.324 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 16627265536, Free: 448

6569984}

14:41:46.324 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 1662

7265536, Free: 4486569984}

14:41:46.324 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 1431830528, Committ

ed: 1229455360}

14:41:46.605 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI TCP Connection(19)-127.0.0.1: (port 61852) connection closed

14:41:46.606 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI TCP Connection(19)-127.0.0.1: close connection

14:41:47.590 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running

14:41:47.594 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.

14:41:47.595 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.

14:41:47.595 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.

14:41:47.596 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.

14:41:47.597 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.

14:41:47.597 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.

14:41:47.598 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.

14:41:47.599 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.

14:41:47.599 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.

14:41:50.130 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI TCP Connection(20)-127.0.0.1: (port 61852) connection closed

14:41:50.130 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI TCP Connection(20)-127.0.0.1: close connection

14:41:51.313 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 16627265536, Free: 448

3686400}

14:41:51.313 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 1662

7265536, Free: 4483686400}

14:41:51.314 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 1431830528, Committ

ed: 1229455360}

----- End of the daemon log --enter code here---
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

Could not dispatch a message to the daemon.

- Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full in

sights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     424.7s (!)

Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
flutter clean
flutter build apk
```